# How do i serialize an empty jsonapi object

Tags: objective-c, json-api

i have a jsonapi object that i need to serialise into a string.

```
{\n  \"data\" : [\n\n  ]\n}
```

but this causes the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]:    
Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

this is the code that i am using to convert the json object into a string:

```
    NSError * error;
NSData * jData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"data"] 
options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *jString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem.(***that does not involve manually removing the \ and \n***)

Comment: Something or someone here is very, very confused. What you displayed is a JSON document converted to a string, and the JSON document is a dictionary with a single key "data", and single value which is an empty array. I have not the slightest idea what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: it causes no problem when the json dictionary actually holds value. when i delete the arrays and send it, this happens. if ic annot solve it, will have to call a different method to pass value for the empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a json object into string you should first get it into a `NSData` then use the encoding of `NSUTF8StringEncoding` to turn it into a `NSString`.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = {\n  \"data\" : [\n\n  ]\n}
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: not sure if my post did was not understandable, but tahts what i had done- and it was throwing the error- modified my post to include the full post.

Comment: saw your edit now. Have you debug this and check that it is correct `[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"data"]` ?